Can't understand how to pass a db session in FastAPI
Now I just import sessionmaker in dao classes and do what I need to:
class BaseDAO:
    model = None

    @classmethod
    async def find_all(cls, **filter_by):
        async with async_session() as session:
            query = select(cls.model).filter_by(**filter_by)
            result = await session.execute(query)
            return result.scalars().all()

I know that there are two other ways:

pass session in endpoint via Depends(get_db):

def get_db() -> Generator:  # pragma: no cover
    """
    Returns a generator that yields a database session

    Yields:
        Session: A database session object.

    Raises:
        Exception: If an error occurs while getting the database session.
    """

    log.debug("getting database session")
    db = get_local_session(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, False)()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:  # pragma: no cover
        log.debug("closing database session")
        db.close()  # pragma: no cover

@router.post("/register")
def register(user_register: UserRegister, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):


The most unclear one. But I was told that it is the best way:
a. By pointing the dependency to an abstract base class rather than a concrete class. This may be a good idea from a code structuring point of view, but can be difficult to describe when we depend on third party classes

class MyProto(abc.ABC):
    ...

@router.get
def my_view_funcion(param: MyProto = Depends()): 
    ...

app = FastApi()
app.dependency_overrides[MyProto] = some_session_factory

b. Pointing a dependency to a stub function that doesn't actually do anything. This can also be used to mark dependencies of the same type, but which should have different meanings.
def get_session_stub():
    raise NotImplementedError  # это реально тело этой функции
    
@router.get
def my_view_funcion(param: Session = Depends(get_session_stub)): 
    ...

app = FastApi()
app.dependency_overrides[get_session_stub] = some_session_factory

It would be great if you could explain to me the last strategy. If it's good, of course :)

I prefer to use db client for this purposes:

from asyncio import current_task
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import AsyncContextManager

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import (
    AsyncSession,
    async_scoped_session,
    create_async_engine,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


class DatabaseClient:
    """Database client."""

    def __init__(self):
        """."""

        async_engine = create_async_engine(
            self.build_url(),
            isolation_level=CONFIG.DB_ISOLATION_LEVEL,
            echo=CONFIG.DB_ECHO,
            pool_recycle=CONFIG.DB_POOL_RECYCLE,
            pool_size=CONFIG.DB_POOL_SIZE,
            max_overflow=CONFIG.DB_MAX_OVERFLOW,
        )
        self.session_factory = async_scoped_session(
            sessionmaker(
                autocommit=False,
                autoflush=False,
                bind=async_engine,
                class_=AsyncSession,
                expire_on_commit=False,
            ),
            scopefunc=current_task,
        )

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def get_async_session(self) -> AsyncContextManager[AsyncSession]:
        """Prepare new session."""

        session = self.session_factory()

        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()


So your repository can look like this:
class PointRepository:
    """Point repository."""

    db: DatabaseClient

    def __init__(self, db: DatabaseClient):
        """."""

        self.db = db

    async def exists(self, point_id: UUID4) -> bool:
        """Check if point exist."""

        async with self.db.get_async_session() as session:
            return (
                await session.execute(
                    exists(select(Point).where(Point.id == point_id)).select()
                )
            ).scalar()

And not you can init the client and the repository and use exists method without caring about a session.
